# Different Table format style in datatable using laravel framework

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Using datatable is it possible to achieve below mentioned table format?

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span  this may help you !!

Comment: Using normal html we can do that but i am asking using datatable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: [datatables](https://datatables.net/) is a jQuery plugin, which can use a html table, so why wouldn't you be able to do this?

Comment: not able to declare rowspan inside the <tbody> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use rowspan on  not in tbody.
Example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan)